# Jenkins setup on kubernetes using helm charts github error

Tags: azure, github, kubernetes, jenkins, kubernetes-helm

I am spinning up a new jenkins instance on aks cluster using helm. the pods and services are up and running.

I am getting the following error on jenkins url

```
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No hudson.security.SecurityRealm implementation found for github
    at io.jenkins.plugins.casc.impl.configurators.HeteroDescribableConfigurator.lambda$lookupDescriptor$11(HeteroDescribableConfigurator.java:211)
    at io.vavr.control.Option.orElse(Option.java:321)
    at io.jenkins.plugins.casc.impl.configurators.HeteroDescribableConfigurator.lookupDescriptor(HeteroDescribableConfigurator.java:210)
    at io.jenkins.plugins.casc.impl.configurators.HeteroDescribableConfigurator.lambda$configure$3(HeteroDescribableConfigurator.java:84)
    at io.vavr.Tuple2.apply(Tuple2.java:238)
    at io.jenkins.plugins.casc.impl.configurators.HeteroDescribableConfigurator.configure(HeteroDescribableConfigurator.java:83)
    at io.jenkins.plugins.casc.impl.configurators.HeteroDescribableConfigurator.check(HeteroDescribableConfigurator.java:92)
    at io.jenkins.plugins.casc.impl.configurators.HeteroDescribableConfigurator.check(HeteroDescribableConfigurator.java:55)
    at io.jenkins.plugins.casc.BaseConfigurator.configure(BaseConfigurator.java:350)
    at io.jenkins.plugins.casc.BaseConfigurator.check(BaseConfigurator.java:286)
    at io.jenkins.plugins.casc.ConfigurationAsCode.lambda$checkWith$8(ConfigurationAsCode.java:776)
    at io.jenkins.plugins.casc.ConfigurationAsCode.invokeWith(ConfigurationAsCode.java:712)
    at io.jenkins.plugins.casc.ConfigurationAsCode.checkWith(ConfigurationAsCode.java:776)
    at io.jenkins.plugins.casc.ConfigurationAsCode.configureWith(ConfigurationAsCode.java:761)
    at io.jenkins.plugins.casc.ConfigurationAsCode.configureWith(ConfigurationAsCode.java:637)
    at io.jenkins.plugins.casc.ConfigurationAsCode.configure(ConfigurationAsCode.java:306)
    at io.jenkins.plugins.casc.ConfigurationAsCode.init(ConfigurationAsCode.java:298)
Caused: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at hudson.init.TaskMethodFinder.invoke(TaskMethodFinder.java:104)
Caused: java.lang.Error
    at hudson.init.TaskMethodFinder.invoke(TaskMethodFinder.java:110)
    at hudson.init.TaskMethodFinder$TaskImpl.run(TaskMethodFinder.java:180)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.runTask(Reactor.java:296)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins$5.runTask(Jenkins.java:1151)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$2.run(Reactor.java:214)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.run(Reactor.java:117)
    at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:68)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused: org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.ReactorException
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.execute(Reactor.java:282)
    at jenkins.InitReactorRunner.run(InitReactorRunner.java:49)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins.executeReactor(Jenkins.java:1184)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins.<init>(Jenkins.java:976)
    at hudson.model.Hudson.<init>(Hudson.java:85)
    at hudson.model.Hudson.<init>(Hudson.java:81)
    at hudson.WebAppMain$3.run(WebAppMain.java:298)
Caused: hudson.util.HudsonFailedToLoad
    at hudson.WebAppMain$3.run(WebAppMain.java:315)
**strong text**
  kubectl version --short
 `Flag --short has been deprecated, and will be removed in the future. The -- 
short output will become the default.
W0818 10:40:09.117917  765920 azure.go:92] WARNING: the azure auth plugin is deprecated in 
v1.22+, unavailable in v1.25+; use https://github.com/Azure/kubelogin instead.
To learn more, consult https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn- 
authz/authentication/#client-go-credential-plugins
Client Version: v1.24.1
Kustomize Version: v4.5.4
Server Version: v1.22.6
WARNING: version difference between client (1.24) and server (1.22) exceeds the supported 
minor version skew of +/-1



`enter code here`helm list -n g2-jenkins-azure-test
   NAME    NAMESPACE               REVISION        UPDATED                                 STATUS          
   CHART           APP VERSION
   jenkins g2-jenkins-azure-test   3               2022-08-12 10:29:30.9065209 -0400 EDT   
   deployed        jenkins-4.1.14  2.346.2`enter code here`
```

in Jenkins jcasc file this is the security realm for github

securityRealm:
github:
clientID: "38acb7699231c4c74e60"
clientSecret: "f1dd6f3e35e53c211984f19fa40dda52e4db53a6"
githubApiUri: "https://api.github.com"
githubWebUri: "https://github.com"
oauthScopes: "read:org,user:email,repo"

Comment: *version difference between client (1.24) and server (1.22) exceeds the supported 
minor version skew of +/-1*

Answer (score 0):

the issue was that it was missing the github auth plugins